# Java RMI Connection error in local

Tags: java, rmi

I don't know why but i'm getting this error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getNbMots(Unknown Source)
    at tp1.Serveur.main(Serveur.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 7 more
```

With this code:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
        // if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) { System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); }
        // 1099 est le port sur lequel sera publié le service, il s'agit du port par défaut de RMI. Nous devons le préciser à la fois sur le registry et à la fois à la création du stub.
        LectFichierInt skeleton = (LectFichierInt) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new LectFichierImpl(), 1099); // Génère un stub vers notre service qui pourra être accessible via le port précisé. L’implémentation du service étant CalcImpl
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Parametres.PORT); //Crée un registre
        registry.rebind("LectFichier", skeleton); // publie notre stub sous le nom "Calc«  dans le registre précédemment créé
        System.out.println(skeleton.getNbMots(1, 3000) + " yolooo ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use port 2015 and I have make a `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 2015 -j ACCEPT`. 
Another small bug, if I don't write the `System.out.println(...);` the program starts and stops without showing an error.

Comment: Are you running the client on the same host as the server? Looks like a case of RMI FAQ item A.1 to me.

Comment: The server won't start then the client can't connect. But the same code on another machine works...

Comment: Why are you calling your own remote method in the server? Don't do that. NB The result of `exportObject()` is a stub, not a skeleton.

Comment: i've found THE SOLUTION for my error ^^ And yep i've seen that this is called stub but the name don't change anythings ^^

Comment: I didn't say it would change anything. It would be ridiculous to suppose that changing a variable name would fix a software problem. But you shouldn't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

So there is the solution. The problem is : "Unknown" why ? i don't know :D

Well, you just need to make a static declaration of LectFichierInt skeleton in the class. Like :

```
public class Yolo {
static LectFichierInt skeleton; // or stub don't cry :P

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
        skeleton = (LectFichierInt) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new LectFichierImpl(), 1099);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Parametres.PORT); 
        registry.rebind("LectFichier", skeleton);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Enjoy, now if you have the same problem, try this to fix that bug ;)

Comment: Actually it is the Registry which needs to be static. Otherwise it can get garbage-collected. Hard to see how making the stub static solved this problem. I repeat that this is not a skeleton but a stub. Don't misuse standard terminology. RMI had skeletons too back in the day (still does for the Registry), and they were different things.